# How do you reply or comment to someone on Area 51 Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, area-51

I created a proposal [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/91626/architecture-recommendations), walked away for a second after asking the first question, and the proposal was closed. Did it really get five votes to be closed that quickly?

Also I believe the person that closed it did so in error. The question I posted, and the Stack Exchange proposal in general, could never be asked on [the programmers Stack Exchange site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour). They mark all recommendation questions as off-topic as policy. So does every other programming Stack Exchange site that I've seen, including [the game development one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour). The whole idea was not to drain from the others, but to create a centralized location where off-topic ones could be forwarded and debated.

I'm still a bit shocked at how fast it was closed though. I don't know how to reply to that user in a way that they can see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the [create new discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?post-text=Proposal%3a+%5b**Architecture+Recommendations**%5d%5b1%5d%0a%0a++%5b1%5d%3ahttp%3a%2f%2farea51.stackexchange.com%2fproposals%2f91626%2farchitecture-recommendations&tags=technology&authCode=GD0fx9zycd8v0cGHg9hJBDTYSk8Qipww0rvrzXnnylM%3d) button on that page if you want to discuss further why you think closing it was an error. The person who closed the question will see that and may choose to respond.

Your proposal was closed by a moderator (see the diamond after his name). Moderator decisions are instantly binding.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the closure:

If the question was closed on Programmers, it is likely because they felt a ***"which language would be best"*** discussion is not a good fit for SE in general — but *not* because the subject is outside their scope.

Programmers SE was create *specifically* for questions about languages, frameworks, tools, databases, or overall design choices. If you have a  really specific question that could be answered authoritatively within the framework of a Stack Exchange site, it would be allowed.

But Area 51 was designed to create sites that expand into *new* subject spaces. We cannot create these quasi-alternatives to site {X} on the premise that *my question got closed there* unless it's because we've expanded outside their scope.